# Creating a DataSource in AWS Machine Learning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, machine-learning

I am trying to add a DataSource to AWS Machine Learning.
I am using S3 to host the file. 
When trying to add the S3file I briefly get the message "Verifying permissions on the S3 file" and then "Error occurred". 
I am getting a 400 error in the JavaScript console.
File permissions are set to public.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid being File permissions set to public won't help. The user account with which you are trying to create `DataSource` must have required permission. Go through [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/reference.html#controlling-access-to-amazon-ml-resources-by-using-iam) and set your IAM permissions accordingly.

P.S - As best practice do **not** keep your file to publc.